# How to find the component path in AEM Touch UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, aem, aem-touch-ui

I want to e.g. fetch the path `/content/branc/region/microsite_name/en/mypage/jcr:content/par/mycomponent` in jQuery.

I am able to fetch the page path using Granite.author.page.

Code to fetch page path:

```
(function ($, $document, author) {
    "use strict";   
$(document).on("dialog-ready", function() {
    var path = author.page`enter code here`.path; //This works
    var component = author.component.path; //This is not working
    console.log("component path " +component);
   });
})($, $(document), Granite.author);
```

Kindly advice how to fetch the component path in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resourcetype is available in `Granite.author.DialogFrame.currentDialog.editable.type`. The path in the type field is not absolute and lacks the '/apps or /libs' part. If you are interested in the absolute path try `Granite.author.DialogFrame.currentDialog.editable.config.dialog`

Answer (score 1):

As @sharath-madappa points out, the `resourceType` is available from `Granite.author.DialogFrame.currentDialog.editable.type`.

If you want the exact path to the component that invoked the dialog, you can use `Granite.author.DialogFrame.currentDialog.editable.path`.

More documentation about it: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/jsdoc/ui-touch/editor-core/Granite.author.DialogFrame.html